# Correct pronounce for "You have one message" in French

Tags: grammaire

I need advice, which one of French prompts for "You have one message" is more correct from grammar and pronunciation sides.

Example 1: https://soundcloud.com/reni-min/example-1

Example 2: https://soundcloud.com/reni-min/example-2

TYIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

example-1 is **not** correct as "*message*" is of the masculine gender (=> **UN** message) in french while you can hear "*une message*".

example-2 is correct on the grammatical side and acceptable from the pronunciation side... taking into account that the voice is synthetic.